# Angular 8 - Lazy Loading of Module not working

Tags: angular, routes, load, lazy-evaluation

As shown in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbbhgp, I am trying to achieve a very simple routing which involve lazy loading of module. When I click on the "link", it seems not working. I expected to see the word "Student Page" appear, but it did not happen.

Note that I would like the solution to involve the use of import api (the newer syntax to lazy load module)

Comment: You are missing your routing to component in your child module.

Comment: please include any console snapshot that would help the other person to relate with the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you haven't added routing to your student module.

Fork of your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrnrxj

The student module needs to use `.forChild()` when declaring routes since it is a child module.

```
const routes:Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StudentComponent } 
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [StudentComponent]
})
export class StudentModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a `Routes` for `Student.routing.module`?

Since you have directed the `student.module`, but you might have not provided from there what component you have been show.

If you have not created to `Student.routing.module`, create one and provide a default route in the same module.

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {path: '', component:StudentComponent } ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the routes of the lazy loaded module and specify the root component of the lazy loaded module.